# Tool to post json to a url

Tags: json, httpclient

Is there a quick tool (http client) that I can use to post different data to a Url for testing purpose. Like posting json object, modifying the headers (POST, PUT) for testing RESTful web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't used it in that way myself I'm pretty sure http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ could do that for you with it's Request Builder.

Answer (score 4):

There's an [advanced REST Client plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) you can get for Google Chrome which I've used successfully.  I find it a bit more straight forward and less confusing than Fiddler2.

Another really popular REST client that I've seen a lot of people use is [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).